# How to push a new item in an array with Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to push a new item in an array in firebase

I've tried doing this but it just replace the first item of the array in firebase

```
usersUid: [{ usersUid: player.userUid }]
```

Provider:

```
addPlayer(chatRoomUid: string, player: Player): Promise<any> {
    return this._getDoc(chatRoomUid).set({
      players: [
        {
          userUid: player.userUid,
          userName: player.userName,
          characterUid: player.characterUid,
          characterName: player.characterName
        }
      ],
      usersUid: [{ usersUid: player.userUid }]
    }, { merge: true });
  }

private _getDoc(chatRoomUid: string): AngularFirestoreDocument {
    return this.afs.doc(`chat_rooms/${chatRoomUid}`);
  }
```

Model:

```
usersUid: string[];
```

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

What I got:

[image: what i got]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

`usersUid: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(player.userUid)` works

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: Only disadvantage this has that the list can't contain any duplicatie values.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `set` you overwrite the existing data, in your case the chatroom.
If you want to add a new ID to userUid, first you need to get the current list of Ids,
then changing this line:

```
usersUid: [{ usersUid: player.userUid }]
```

to:

```
usersUid: listOfIds
```

list OfIds should be an array, not an object. (e.g [1,2,3,4,5])

Comment: What do you mean by listOfIds? I also did use `.update()` and it still overwrite the first array

Answer (score 0):

use `.push` not `.set` on your chat_rooms array

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#adding-new-items

```
const itemsRef = db.list('items');
itemsRef.push({ name: newName });
```

Comment: `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreDocument<DocumentData>'.ts(2339)`

Comment: ther are docs for cloud firestore too: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#adding-documents-to-a-collection